# Number theory involving primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

1. Find all $(a,b,c,d,q,w,p)$ with $a,b,c,d,q,w$ positive integers and $p$ prime such that $p|1 + 2 b q^a + 2 b^2 q^{2 a} + 2 d w^c + 4 b d q^a w^c + 2 d^2 w^{2 c}$ and $p+1=abcdqw(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)(q-1)(w-1)$

I decided to share my own problem. Try to solve them!

Hint: You could use Fermat's little theorem, but there is lemma that trivializes the problem (which can be proved by FLT)

Comment: Why not create separate questions for different problems?

Comment: @Aravind Ok, I removed one.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $z=bq^a+dw^c$, we get $p|2z^2+2z+1$, so that $p|(2z+1)^2+1$.
This means that $-1$ is a square modulo $p$; on the other hand the second equation implies that $p \equiv -1$ (mod 4), which is a contradiction (as it is well-known that $-1$ is not a square modulo such primes). So there are no solutions.

Comment: Could you give a reference or pehaps prove it? You are in one of the correct ways.

Comment: If $a^2 \equiv -1$ (mod $p$) for $p \equiv 3$ (mod 4), then then raising both sides to the power $(p-1/2)$ gives: $a^{p-1} \equiv -1$ (mod $p$).